# JS front end, Flask back end; Authentication question

Tags: javascript, authentication, flask

I have a fairly simple setup I am working on.

- flask backend, listening on port 8000, accepting JSON, returning JSON. This is served by uwsgi.
- very straightforward JS/Bootstrap/JQuery front end with some forms and buttons. OnClick() creates a JSON and calls POST with URL "/api"
- everything served by Nginx.

  - JS site served by NGINX on port 80"
  - /api" proxied to localhost:8000
  - uwsgi at 8000 served by uwsgi_pass

Everything works decently. My question now is authentication.

I want the API behind a basic username/password at least. How can I make the front end javascript call the API with that authentication, without hard coding it into the JS script?

I want the user who visits http://my-server to be asked a username/password. I then want my JS script call the "/api" with the same credentials passed by the user.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I don't have a lot of insight into OAUTH2/JWT etc that I find when I google for this, but clearly I don't know what I am googling for. I am ok learning regardless of the complexity.

Most of the links I see that I understand talks about setting a username/password for the main page via nginx settings, but I dont' understand how those are "passed" through to the Flask API. Also, I don't know whether Flask itself should have some kind of authentication, or if that's handled by uwsgi or nginx or ...

Help? :)

Comment: In "without hard coding it into the JS script?", what does "it" refer to?

Comment: The credentials basically. For instance, I can set up authentication via Flask (say username/password), and then in my JS call I can hard code that when calling "/api"... right? Wouldnt that work? (That's what I do not want to do, but that would work, right?)

Comment: Why'd you think that you have to hardcode an authentication into your app? You wan't to protect your API from external access with some auth but don't know how to store your key in your webpage for _you_ to access it?